# Intellj 2019.1 version: import multi-project gradle not working

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Intellj 2019.1 version: import multi-project gradle not working:

```
rootProject
subproject1
subproject2
```

Import gradle (multi-projects)

```
File - new -- project with existing source
```

specify the directory for the root project:

Only the root project is imported, there is no subprojects.

sync filed:

**Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.**

What does this message mean? How to fix it?

Comment: do you have a `settings.gradle` file in the root project directory ?  BTW a better way to import existing Gradle project into IDEA is from menu " File -> Open " and select the root project directory; then you'll reach the Gradle import wizard.

Comment: yes. there is settings.gradle. I also tried the way you suggested. gradle command line works great.

Comment: sync failed with error message I do not understand.

Comment: what is yourGradle version ?  (your system-wide version, and Wrapper version (if you are using wrapper)

Comment: this is similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2

Comment: gradle: 4.0, gradlew: 4.5.1. But I do not have java 11 installed.

Comment: Does Intellij come with its own gradle version?

Comment: anything to do with Window defender? It pops up saying some features are blocked and I click "accept".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Most probably updating the gradle wrapper would solve the problem. What Java have you installed if not the 11? Check the [gradle notes per release](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html) to see when was the support added for your version. For 11 it was added on 5.0 and for JDK 12 on 5.4.

Comment: resolved by updating wrapper. Thanks.