# java version change from eclipse isn't working(gradle)

Tags: java, gradle

I wanted to create a Gradle class, but there was an error

> An internal error occurred during: "Create Gradle project(s)". Could
>   not determine java version from '13.0.1'.

while creating a Gradle project.

so I googled it and found that Gradle(5.6.1) is compatible with java 8. and I re-downloaded java 8.
also changed environment variable, JDK Compliance to 1.8, and Installed JREs to jre1.8.0.

but there is same error again! could you tell me whether I omitted something while re-version java? or this is not about the version of java?

sorry for bad English.

Comment: As an alternate solution, Gradle 6 supports Java 13, if you don't mind updating.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2. It would help if you could provide much more details about your system, see similar questions.

Comment: thanks, Crummy, tkruse! i solved problem by using Gradle6. thank you for advice. it really helped me.