# Gradle could not determine Java version from '14.0.1'

Tags: gradle

I have the following error when I try to build on Gradle:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '14.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have Gradle 6.3 installed. The build uses the Gradle wrapper using Gradle 5.1.1. Do i have to downgrade Java?

Comment: Duplicate: [Gradle: Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2)  
Same situation with different gradle-wrapper and systemwide gradle versions, where the gradle wrapper version is an older one (5.1.1) that doesn't support Java 14.

Answer (score 6):

As per Gradle release notes ([Link](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html)):

Compatibility Notes

A Java version between 8 and 13 is required to execute Gradle. Java 14 and later versions are not yet supported.

Java 6 and 7 can still be used for compilation and forked test execution. Just like Gradle 5.x, any supported version of Java can be used for compile or test.

I think you need to downgrade your Java version.

Comment: As per OP's comment the build is using Gradle 5.1.1 which [supports Java 11](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html#java-11-runtime-support) only.

Comment: What a mess. How would you even go about getting an older version of Gradle if you needed it?

Answer (score 1):

Is suspicious in not reporting a Gradle version.

Could you add the output of .gradlew -version on your machine?
My first guess would be that you have a Linux distribution packaged version of Gradle which is usually a rebuilt version with selected patches and not something that matches the official Gradle releases.

In addition, when looking at the thrift repo gradle wrapper I see they are still using 5.1.1 which was not Java 12 compatible. You need at least Gradle 5.4.

for more info https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10804

Comment: Hello! My gradlew output was => `------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          14.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 14.0.1+7)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
`