# Could not determine java version from '14.0.1'. Android studio, LibDGX, on Windows 10

Tags: java, android-studio

In android studio I tried to use libDGX. And when I run the correct code the terminal gave me thi error. How to fi this problem:

```
1.(...my folders...)gradlew desktop:run

2.FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

3.* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '14.0.1'.

4.* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Maybe you could downgrade your java version. To execute Gradle, the version of Java has to be between 8 and 13. Java 14 and later versions was not supported yet to my knowledge. Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411897/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-14-0-1

Comment: I have downgraded the version of JDK to 13. 0.2 :                                                                                java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)                          But it still shows another type of error:                                                                                         Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema'.
How to fix that? I might be stupid till end of this problem, huh.

Comment: And I also have this type of the problem:                                                                                       Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler                                    How to fix that also???

Comment: Have you set your JAVA_HOME to the current location of your jdk? That might be the reason of your second problem. And it could indirectly cause your first problem. I recommend checking it out first.

Comment: I have already set JAVA_HOME to the current location of the jdk file. But it is still in its own position. And if you pay attontion it is not repositoryv2. It is just a repository. A problem which you said is produced by repositoryv2 if article is true which I have read. [Article](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50650693.shtml)

Comment: I'm learning from udacity for LibDGX. [This code](https://github.com/udacity/ud405) is which I'm using. Can U download and run it's first part. Which is called 1.2.01-Demo-GettingStartedWithLibGDX   if possible. And if works in your case, it means I have problems.