# What means "project" keyword in the gradle.build file?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle.build file https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations with

```
project(':java5').archivesBaseName = 'annotations-java5'
```

line and I have a error there:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'java-annotations'.
> Project with path ':java5' could not be found in root project 'java-annotations'.
```

I have no idea what is "project" keyword syntax, could you point me to the proper documentation? Could you tell me what went wrong during "gradle build"?

Thank you!

Comment: The contents in a `build.gradle` file are not really keywords, they all map to properties or methods in the Gradle API or plugins running in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The [project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#project-java.lang.String-) method locates a project by path, which in this case is `java5` relative to the root project (indicated by the leading `:`). As seen in the javadoc this method returns another `Project` instance, and here its `archiveBaseName` property is accessed.

Comment: But I have "java5" directory inside! why it can't be found?

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net how are you running the gradle task? you are of course right, the `java5` project exists (see `settings.gradle`)

Comment: @FOX "gradle build"

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net that may be the problem, you should use the gradle wrapper via `./gradlew` to make sure the right version is used

Comment: @FOX after the fix described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359875/1999752 the ./gradlew command fails with same error message "Project with path ':java5' could not be found in root project 'java-annotations'.
"

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net thats very very weird as the project clearly exists, if you are sure that you are in the right directory and everything else is correct, then maybe try deleting the `build` and `.gradle` caches, sometimes gradle does stupid stuff and magically stops after some cache clearing.

Comment: @FOX nothing helps. Same error

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net I really don't know what you are doing wrong, I just cloned the repo and it built successfully (openjdk 11, `JDK_5` = openjdk 8). The only requirement was setting the `JDK_5` env var.

Comment: @FOX I am sorry, gradle.settings was damaged, this question was created by mistake