# Could not determine java version from '11.0.12'

Tags: flutter, dart

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '11.0.12'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output

The plugin `contact_picker` could not be built due to the issue above.

My project correctly  run but I'm  build app bundle  so its  show its Error

Comment: If my answer did not help you, please add more information regarding your issue. For an example look at how the question is formated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you should look at the solution in this parcitular question.

[Gradle: Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2)