# How to run an old version of android react native project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

How to run an existing older version of react native project with version 0.55.4 without upgrading it, the project is made by React-native CLI?

> I just npm install in the project, then npx react-native run-android [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5U3Z.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get in the image it's not related to react-native it's caused from your java jdk version you can check [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358107/gradle-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-2) with the same issue and hope it works for you.